# XNA model with bones

Tags: xna

I created a model in Blender and then I used armature to create some pose. How can I display this pose in XNA/MonoGame? I can't find any solution. I use model exported to fbx file.
My only code is here and it draws model without armature effect:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // Copy any parent transforms.
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[myModel.Bones.Count];
        myModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        // Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in myModel.Meshes)
        {
            // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well as our camera and projection.
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * Matrix.CreateRotationY(modelRotation)
                    * Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f),
                    aspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
            }
            // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
            mesh.Draw();
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: This requires a ton of work which I doubt anyone would want to write down in a post. Furthermore, I doubt it'll even fit in a single post. But here's a link that'll send you in the right direction: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model

Comment: I am trying to use this, but I get an exception in line "AnimationClip clip = skinningData.AnimationClips["Take 001"];" that there is no "Take 001" key in dictionary. What can be wrong? Something with my model?

Comment: As the error message kinda states, it can't detect an animation clip called "Take 001" in your model file... I can't tell you why, but that's what it says. My guess is, it's something wrong with the model.

Comment: Thanks. Now it work. Last question: can I stop/pause animation and display model with "beginnig pose" (without armature effect)?